# Filter an entity by a list of tags using JPA specification API

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery, criteriabuilder

I have a Guest entity which have a set of Tag entities in a OneToMany relationship. My goal is to filter out Guests who have an exact set of Tags.

E.g.

```
Tag vip = new Tag(1, "VIP");
Tag friend = new Tag(2, "FRIEND");

Guest guest1 = new Guest(1, "John");
guest1.addTag(vip);
guest1.addTag(friend);

Guest guest2 = new Guest(2, "alice");
guest2.addTag(friend);
```

Filtering

1. by vip should return guest1 only
2. by friend should return guest1 and guest2
3. by vip AND friend should return guest1 only

The first 2 filtering are working well, but the 3rd one returns an empty list.

Here a code snipset

Guest entity

```java
@Entity
public class Guest {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "guest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    // getters, setters and hash here
}
```

Tag entity

```java
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private UUID tagId;

    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "guest_id")
    private Guest guest;

    // getters, setters and hash here
}
```

I Tried with this specification

Specification

```java
public static Specification<Guest> hasExactTags(List<UUID> tagIds) {
    return (Root<Guest> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        Join<Guest, Tag> join = root.join("tags");

        for (UUID tagId : tagIds) {
             predicates.add(cb.equal(join.get("tagId"), tagId));
        }

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

But the 3rd filtering (filter by vip AND friend should return guest1 only) doesn't work as expected. It returns an empty list.

What is wrong with this query?

I've also tried this query, the 3rd filtering (filter by vip AND friend should return guest1 only) returns both guest1 and guest2. And when the order of the filter is changed (filter by friend AND vip) it returns guest1

```java
public static Specification<Guest> hasExactTags(List<UUID> tagIds) {
    return (Root<Guest> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

        Subquery<Guest> guestSubquery = query.subquery(Guest.class);
        Root<Tag> tagRoot = guestSubquery.from(Tag.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (UUID tagId : tagIds) {
             guestSubquery.select(tagRoot.get("guest"))
                    .where(cb.equal(tagRoot.get("tagId"), tagId));

                predicates.add(cb.in(root).value(guestSubquery));
        }

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

Comment: Try writing out what your specification would be in SQL or JPQL and the problems might make sense. First is "select .. FROM Guest g join g.tags tag where tag.tagId = :tagId1 AND tag.tagId = :tagId2". The tagId value can't be both the first and the second value at the same time. You don't want a join on tags in the main query. Something more like "select .. FROM Guest g where exists (select 1 from Tag tag where tag.tagId = :tagId1 And tag.guest = g) AND exists (select 1 from Tag tag where tag.tagId = :tagId2 And tag.guest = g)"

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Chris. That is what i'm doing with the 2nd specification but using IN instead of EXIST. But both do not work

Comment: Turn on SQL logging then to see what is actually generated - that will help you figure out what is going wrong. Your Subquery is not what I suggested though - You are using the same subquery instance in the loop, so it isn't doing what you think it is doing.